# How do I structure a Javascript library/module so that users can do partial imports using path (slash)?

Tags: javascript, module

I'm not sure I'm even asking the question in the correct way.  Basically I have a project with many modules.  I would like users to be able to `import * from 'myModule'` and I would also like for the option to import only a specific function using a path like `import thing1, {thing2} from 'myModule/things'`
Will someone point me to or tell me the name of the thing I'm attempting to do?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-exports

Comment: Thanks @Bergi I looked that up and it seemed straightforward but am struggling to get it working.  I've created a different issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69998956/unable-to-resolve-module-sedcommon-epilog-using-module-subpaths-defined-in-pac