# Unable to resolve module `sedcommon/epilog` using module subpaths defined in package.json exports

Tags: javascript, react-native, module, node-modules

I have a module that is created outside my react-native v61.5 app that I'd like to name the imports using the subpaths.
I am hosting the package and it gets pulled down and I can import from the defined "main" entry in the package.json file however when I attempt to load say 'sedcommon/epilog' I get message "bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `sedcommon/epilog`"

`import {EPILOG_RT_EEG_DATA_RECEIVED} from 'sedcommon/epilog';` is what I would like to accomplish.
`import {EPILOG_RT_EEG_DATA_RECEIVED} from 'sedcommon';` works but I would rather use the subpath.

My `sedcommon` package.json looks like this:

```
   {
    "name": "sedcommon",
    "main": "build/index.js",
    "version": "2.1.4",
    "exports": {
        "./epilog/*": "./build/epilog/*.js"        
    },
...
```

I have tried various version of the export such as `"./epilog": "./build/epilog/index"` and a couple others all giving the same error message.

The documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#package-entry-points) seems straightforward but I'm not able to make it work.  The `./epilog` folder has multiple *.js files and an index.js file.

```
node -v
v16.8.0
```

I'm also using typescript in this RN app.  Here are my ts settings

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            // when changed here also change in babel.config.js
            "*": ["node_modules/*", "*"],
            "actions": ["./src/actions/index"],
            "components": ["./src/components/index"],
            "constants": ["./src/constants/index"],
            "images/*": ["./src/images/*"],
            "lib/*": ["./src/lib/*"],
            "reducers/*": ["./src/reducers/*"],
            "reducers": ["./src/reducers/index"],
            "sagas/*": ["./src/sagas/*"],
            "screens/*": ["./src/screens/*"],
            "types": ["./src/types/index"],
            "utils": ["./src/utils/index"]
        },
        "plugins": [{"transform": "ts-optchain/transform"}],
        "target": "esnext" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */,
        "module": "ESNext" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */,
        "lib": ["es6", "es2018.promise"] /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */,
        "allowJs": true /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */,
        "checkJs": false /* Report errors in .js files. */,
        "jsx": "react" /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */,
        "declaration": true /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */,
        "declarationMap": true /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */,
        "sourceMap": true /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */,
        "noEmit": true /* Do not emit outputs. */,
        "isolatedModules": true /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */,
        "strict": false /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
        "noUnusedLocals": true /* Report errors on unused locals. */,
        "noUnusedParameters": true /* Report errors on unused parameters. */,
        "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */,
        "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
    }
    },
    "setupFiles":["jest.turnOffDev.js"],
    "include": ["./src", "src/types", "src/components/.tsx"],
    "exclude": [
        "./src/screens/*",
        "./tmp/*",
        "**/__tests__/*",
        "**/*/*.test.*",
        "**/__mocks__/*",
        "node_modules",
        "babel.config.js",
        "metro.config.js",
        "jest.config.js"
    ]
}
```

I tried this in another node project using TS and I'm getting the same message as in my RN project... here is that projects TS config

```
 "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noImplicitThis": false,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "declaration": true,
 "outDir": "build",
     "isolatedModules": true
    },
```

Comment: Drop the `*` I think, and reference the exact file: `"./epilog": "./build/epilog/index.js"`

Comment: @Bergi ya tried that same issue, event restarted metro and reinstalled app.  I don't think there is anything in my react-native or typescript settings....added those setting to orig post.

Comment: This appears to be an issue w/ so many conflicting things Typescript, Node version to make it work, module types... I'm giving up :(